# how to find anomalies for a non-normal distribution with seasonality?

Tags: outliers, anomaly-detection

I have a time series broken down by day, and there are gaps in it that I have marked in red:
[image]

the distribution there is not normal

[image]

How do we approach modeling a system that will look for anomalies here if they appear?

Because if you differentiate as I did above and try to set limits, for example, using Z score or IQr, it is obvious that anomalies will be growth that is typical and normal. I don't know how to approach this problem, what methods to use and where to go, please tell me.

[image]